# Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined... Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

I'm new to Vue.js and I'm working with modals. I'm using the `Buefy` framework mostly. This is my example code:

```
<template>
    <section>
        <button class="button is-primary is-small" @click="addModal = true">
              <span>Insert New</span>
            </button>

        <b-modal :active.sync="addModal"
                 has-modal-card
                 trap-focus
                 :destroy-on-hide="false"
                 aria-role="dialog"
                 aria-modal>
            <modal-form v-bind="formProps"></modal-form>
        </b-modal>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
const ModalForm = {
  props: ["tagName", "moreFields"],
  template: `
            <form action="">
                <div class="modal-card" style="width: auto">
                    //input fields here
                    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
                        <button class="button" type="button" @click="$parent.close()">Close</button>
                        <button class="button is-primary" @click="addTag">Add Tag</button>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </form>
        `,
};
export default {
  components: {
    ModalForm,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        tagName: "",
      },
      addModal: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addTag() {
      if (this.data.tagName.trim().length > "") {
        console.log(mydata);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

However, when I try to click the `Add Tag` button, I get the error `Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined...`
There seems to be so many issues with this and I didn't want to duplicate a post, but I've searched around the site and mostly people have typo issues (`method` instead of `methods`). Would it be because of the scope of the modal? That somehow `addTag` isnt visible to it?

How would I fix this?

Comment: Welcome!
I've added vue.js and buefy tags.  
Please add all relevant tags to future questions.  
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my code the difference it that everything you declare in the data() function, is like a local variable to your component. So to access that you do not need to use the `this.data.tagName` you have to access in a straight way.

You must change your code to:

```
if (this.tagName.trim().length > 0) {
   console.log('mydata');
}
```

Your variable mydata is not declared anywhere. So I print a string 'mydata'.

Another thing to change in your code is that, you can't have html code inside your session `<script>` form your `.vue` file. If you would like to use, you must declare a new component or put the code inside the `<template>` session of your `.vue` file.

If you would like to put everything inside template:

template session from `.vue` file:

```
<template>
<section>
    <button class="button is-primary is-small" @click="addModal = true">
          <span>Insert New</span>
        </button>
        <b-modal :active.sync="addModal"
             has-modal-card
             trap-focus
             :destroy-on-hide="false"
             aria-role="dialog"
             aria-modal>
        <modal-form v-bind="formProps">
          <form action="">
            <div class="modal-card" style="width: auto">
            //input fields here
            <footer class="modal-card-foot">
                <button class="button" type="button" @click="$parent.close()">Close</button>
                <button class="button is-primary" @click="addTag">Add Tag</button>
            </footer>
            </div>
        </form>
      </modal-form>
    </b-modal>
</section>
</template>
```

Another option is to move code from your form to a new "component" and import it as a component in your current `.vue` file.

***components/Modalform.vue***

```
<template>
   <form action="">
        <div class="modal-card" style="width: auto">
        //input fields here
        <footer class="modal-card-foot">
        <button class="button" type="button" @click="$parent.close()">Close</button>
        <button class="button is-primary" @click="addTag">Add Tag</button>
        </footer>
        </div>
   </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ModalForm",
};
</script>
```

***page.vue***

```
<template>
  <section>
        <button class="button is-primary is-small" @click="addModal = true">
              <span>Insert New</span>
            </button>

        <b-modal :active.sync="addModal"
                 has-modal-card
                 trap-focus
                 :destroy-on-hide="false"
                 aria-role="dialog"
                 aria-modal>
            <ModalForm v-bind="formProps"></ModalForm>
        </b-modal>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import ModalForm from "@/components/Modalform.vue";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    ModalForm
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I actually show notification in the `if` block. That method is never reached though. If it makes any difference, the actual line inside my if statement is `this.info("Tag name is ok");` where info is a notification component I declared somewhere else. But yeah, Like I said, that method is never reached in the first place

Comment: Maybe its because your props has the same name as the data object. Can you change? Just to confirm?

Comment: Now i'm getting `Property or method "addTag" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`  on top of that one. I'm using code from [here](https://buefy.org/documentation/modal)  under `Launch Component Modal` if you can reproduce

Comment: I do not know if you can use it like that. All your html code must be inside `<template>` tag, You can't declare a `template` in you script session from .vue file. You must declare all html inside <template> session.

Comment: Ahh noted. I'm still new to Vue so I'll read up more on it. I'll update here if there's a breakthrough